# Difference between ASCII values

Tags: c++

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int length(string a)
{
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
int  strdiff(string a)
{
    n=length(a);
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i]<<a[i+1]-a[i];
    }
    cout<<a[n-1]; 
}

int main() {
    string a;
    cin>>a;
    cout<<strdiff(a);
    return 0;
}
```

**Why am i getting garbage value at the end of the output ?How can i remove garbage value from output?**
Please suggest some ways.

Comment: What is the output you are seeing? What output do you want to see?

Comment: Please provide **sample** and **expected** output

Comment: suppose i entered a string like -  abc output should be a1b1c

Comment: and what do you expect when an *abc* is inputted?

Comment: first character of the string and then the difference between the ascii value of first and second character

Comment: can i use char instead of int while declaring function?

Comment: Yes, a function can return a type. char and int are both types.

Comment: BTW, you can replace your `length` function with `string::length()` or `string::size()`.  No reason to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Don't use `<bits/stdc++.h>` as it is a compiler specific header file.  Use `<iostream>` and `<string>` instead.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> int  strdiff(string a)
> {
>     n=length(a);
>     for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
>     {
>         cout<<a[i]<<a[i+1]-a[i];
>     }
>     cout<<a[n-1]; 
> }
> ```

This function contains no `return` statement. This is undefined behavior in C++, and usually results in garbage from the stack being returned to the calling function.